# How should a left-handed person put on his clothes according to Halacha?

Tags: clothing, handedness

Does a left-handed man have to start wearing his clothes from the left side - because his important hand is left, or from the right side - because this is an important hand for most of  people?

Comment: For future reference for all other questions relating to what a lefty should do, you might want to check out R' Paysach Krohn's English-language book on halachos for lefties. It's available free by mail if you call his home; he lives in Queens, New York, and is listed. (Obviously, you might want to pay him for it, and the postage.)

Comment: Thanks, for the information, but I know Hebrew better than English (I live in Israel). Also the question is not for me, but for my child, he is currently 4 years old, so I'll find some book in Hebrew, when he would be a bit older. thanks again.

Comment: For future reference, [the book I mention is also online](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0Byx6sZjO1KzmOTI1ZWU1ZTItZmQ2ZC00ZmNmLWJhMDAtMWY2MTlhYTcyOGU1). (Thanks to [Dr. Melech Tanen](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0ASx6sZjO1KzmZDhwbW5jal8xZndoOHJuZ3Q) for linking to it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Deberziner Zatzal in Shaalos UTshuvos Beer Moshe - Kuntururs Itur Yad - from the right side like all others.

Answer (score 1):

Like everything else that is done for Kabbalistic reasons, a lefty does the same as a righty.

See: http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/left-handed.html

> Which hand a left-handed person should use, depends on which reason a right-handed person is supposed to use their right hand: either because their right hand is more prominent, or because Kabbalistically, the right hand represents the force of Chessed.
>
> The Mishna Berura (4:22) writes that when washing one’s hands, one washes one’s right hand first irrespective as to whether one is right or left-handed. Likewise, everyone should put their right sleeve, etc. in first when getting dressed (See Mishna Berura 2:4). Unlike right-handed people who tie their left shoes first, however, left-handed people should tie their right shoes first (corresponding to which arm they would tie their Tefillin on).